# Group by having clause in teradata

Tags: teradata

A teradata table
as

```
Group_categ id
A            1
A            2
A            3
A            5
A            8
A            9
B            11
C            1
C            2
C            3
C            4
```

need to filter it like

```
Group_categ min_id max _id
A            1       2
A            3       5
A            8       9
B            11      11
C             1       2
C             3       4
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You need to include more information.  How can group a have 3 sets of mins and maxes?

Comment: Seems you want to two consecutive values into a single row: `SELECT Group_categ, Min(id), Max(id)
FROM
 (
   SELECT 
     Group_categ, id, 
     (Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY Group_categ ORDER BY id)-1) / 2 AS grp
   FROM mytab
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1, grp`

Comment: your solution worked,can you give a small explanation for it

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to combine two consecutive rows into a single row:

```
SELECT Group_categ, Min(id), Max(id)
FROM
 (  
   SELECT
      Group_categ, id,
      -- assign the same value to two consecutive rows: 0,0,1,1,2,2,..
      -- -> used in the outer GROUP BY
      (Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY Group_categ ORDER BY id)-1) / 2 AS grp
   FROM mytab
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY Group_categ, grp
```